# GNU Make, generate file with default settings/content when absent

Tags: makefile, build-process, gnu-make, default-value

I would like **make** to either copy a file from the source tree into the target/build directory if it exits or generate an empty/default file if not.

It would be easy to do the following:

```
target/settings.json: src/settings.json
        cp $? $@

src/settings.json:
        echo "default..." > $@
```

But that taints the source repository with a file that could inadvertently be checked into RCS.

Is there a simple make rule that can copy the file if it exits, or just generate the target with a command/copy from some other source?

A GNU-Make specific solution is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the file exists using `$(wildcard)`, so maybe something like this:

```
ifeq ($(wildcard src/settings.json),)
    SETTINGS = tmp/settings.json
else
    SETTINGS = src/settings.json
endif

target/settings.json: $(SETTINGS)
    cp $? $@

tmp/settings.json:
    echo "default..." > $@
```

Comment: You probably want `.INTERMEDIATE: $(SETTINGS)` in the `tmp/` block to have make delete the temporary file when done.